# I need to obtain any ASCII character from a String in Java, but I have issues with escaping

Tags: java, escaping, ascii

In java, I get from an external resource a String which is a character wrapped in ''. For example.

- 'A'
- 'B'
- '\\n'
- '\\t'

I would like to be able to obtain a character from this String, in the case of the examples.

- A
- B
- \n
- \t

With the first two examples it's rather easy. I can just use myString.charAt(1). The problem comes with the special characters. With '\\n' if I use myString.charAt(1) I get \ while if I use myString.charAt(2) I get n.

I have tested many solutions and all have failed, including trying to use replace to delete one \, or using many external libraries.

Comment: `\n` is the text representation of the new line character `X'0A'`. If the string you are reading represents new lines as '\n` (two characters), you need to replace those characters manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the text from an input where new line/tab characters are represented as text instead of their ASCII representation, you need to replace those characters in your String before processing them. One easy way to do that is by replacing all matching characters in the String like this (notice the double backslash):

```
string = string.replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\\t", "\t");
```

Another way to do so is by using an external library like [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) from Apache:

```
string = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(string);
```

If you have a large text input coming from a streaming source, you can detect those characters on the fly while reading from the stream.

Comment: I need a solution that works for any ASCII character, the examples I provided were just examples.

Comment: Maybe you can use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()`

Answer (score 0):

\n and \t are edge cases you will have to treat seperately. You could for example return the char value of a line break when you detect the string \n

```
if(myString.equals("'\\n'")) return 0x0A
```

0x0A is the encoding of a line break in a single character (represented as \n in string litterals), however, if you try to print this character, you will get a line break nothing else